# Line Following Robot to detect a 2x2 matrix

Tags: algorithm, line-following

I need help in making a Line Following Robot with problem statement requires to detect a 2x2 matrix. how do i do detect it without any computer vision?. The arena looks like this

[image]

PROBLEM STATEMENT:
● You shall place your bot at ‘start’ in any direction, in order to perform
line following.

● In the path, there will be several nodes that you have to decode. The
description of the nodes is mentioned below.

○ The node will be a 2 x 2 matrix that you have to sense with
sensors and have to store that matrix.

○ You have to convert that matrix into a 4-bit binary number. If the
number in binary form is ABCD with A, B, C, & D as the bits
detected, the following will be the order of bits.

[image]

Fig. : Top view of Node

○ For example in the above figure a value will be 1000 with A = 1, B
= 0, C = 0, & D = 0.

○ Your bot should display the value of each node in real-time on an
LCD screen. This data can also be displayed on a mobile or laptop
screen via wireless communication between both.

○ Your bot will cross a node by first encountering C & D cells and
then A & B cells.

● After reaching point A by following the line robot will encounter a node
which it has to detect and decode it into speed by the below-mentioned
method. Then it has to travel to another point B by following the black
line at a speed less than the decoded value, failure to do so would result
in deduction of points. In case the bot crosses the line, human
intervention would be allowed but points would be deducted for it.

○ You have to convert that binary number into a decimal number
and if the decimal number is x then you have to travel at a speed
less than equal to (x/5)m/s.

● After reaching point B bot will again encounter a node with value 0000
and it would denote that the speed limit is over. The bot has to follow
the line again, according to the same rules as mentioned above. It would
then reach point C.

● After reaching C it would again detect a node that would be decoded
into an angle (), the formula for which is mentioned below.

○ If the obtained number after decoding and converting it to decimal
is x then the correct lane would be at an angle of x*10 degrees.

○ You can find the correct lane at this angle in clockwise as well as in
anticlockwise direction.

● Bot then has to follow a circle and has to reach a lane at angle  from the
lane where you left for following the line.

● Following the lane at the decoded angle would result in a path to the
goal point.

● Following the above directions, the bot would reach the Finish area.
There it has to show the message “FINISH” on an LCD display.
NOTE:

● A robot has to detect a total of 3 nodes in its path.

● The bot will be allowed to transverse the maze part only once

Comment: please remove all of the text that is irrelevant to the actual question ... for example, the info about the wooden blocks is not relevant to the question about detecting the matrix

Comment: Quite an elaborate assignment. What sensors does the robot have?

Comment: i am trying to make it work using ir sensors.